# Name Server is not getting updated

Tags: digital-ocean, amazon-route53, nameservers

I have changed name server of `mypleaks.com` like 24 hours back but it is still not updated.

It's still giving me below name servers which is old:-

```
Name Server: ns-****.awsdns-**.org
Name Server: ns-***.awsdns-**.com
Name Server: ns-****.awsdns-**.co.uk
Name Server: ns-***.awsdns-**.net
```

then tested it and got this result on [zonemaster](https://zonemaster.iis.se/?resultid=387b0fc8ee96d634)

where it's giving three Errors like below:-

1. No common nameserver IP addresses between child.
2. Parent has nameserver(s) not listed at the child
3. None of the nameservers listed at the parent are listed at the child.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is offtopic as not related to programming.

You are in a lame delegation case, the list of nameservers do not match at the registry and in your own.

If you query the parent zone, you get now:

```
$ dig @a.gtld-servers.net mypleaks.com NS +noall +nodnssec +auth

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.1-Ubuntu <<>> @a.gtld-servers.net mypleaks.com NS +noall +nodnssec +auth
; (2 servers found)
;; global options: +cmd
mypleaks.com.       172800  IN  NS  ns-107.awsdns-13.com.
mypleaks.com.       172800  IN  NS  ns-613.awsdns-12.net.
mypleaks.com.       172800  IN  NS  ns-1069.awsdns-05.org.
mypleaks.com.       172800  IN  NS  ns-1710.awsdns-21.co.uk.
```

But if you query these nameservers they do not believe to be authoritative on your domain:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
mypleaks.com.       300 IN  NS  ns1.digitalocean.com.
mypleaks.com.       300 IN  NS  ns2.digitalocean.com.
mypleaks.com.       300 IN  NS  ns3.digitalocean.com.
```

So you need to go back to Amazon and make the configuration needed so that all these 4 nameservers (or others as provided by Amazon) are indeed authoritative for your domain (in which case the second reply will be the same as the first, which is currently not the case).